# Displaying nav if path equals path

Tags: php

I have a php page with two navs.  One is an admin nav, the other is public.  using the code below I'm trying to determine the directory i'm in and depending on that show the proper nav.  I feel like this php snippet should work.

```
<?php

    $public = APP_PUBLIC_PATH;
    $admin = APP_ADMIN_PATH;

    if(is_dir($public)) {
        $publicnav = "showme";
        $adminnav = "hideme";
    }
    else if (is_dir($admin)) {
        $publicnav = "hideme";
        $adminnav = "showme";
    }
?>

<nav class="<?php echo $publicnav; ?">
<nav class="<?php echo $admin; ?">
```

I've also tried the following:

```
<?php

    $public = APP_PUBLIC_PATH;
    $admin = APP_ADMIN_PATH;

    if(is_dir($public)) {
        $publicnav = "showme";
        $adminnav = "hideme";
    }
    else {
        $publicnav = "hideme";
        $adminnav = "showme";
    }
?>

<nav class="<?php echo $publicnav; ?>">
<nav class="<?php echo $admin; ?>">
```

Comment: *I feel like this php snippet should work.* Great, what's the question? You're not telling us what's wrong.

Comment: by 'directory i'm' do you refer to the path on disk of  your defined const? because that's what is_dir checks for

Comment: the issue is that it's not working, and like @csminb said it's probably because I'm using the wrong function.  I'll explain what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to determine which subdirectory the user is in and display the nav according to that directory, the two directories are public or admin.

And I tried using my 'APP_PUBLIC_PATH' and 'APP_ADMIN_PATH' which are already defined in my config with those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is_dir only checks to see if the path you provided is a directory or not. Your goal is to check whether the current path is for the admin or for a regular user?

Look into the $_SERVER superglobal variable on how to get the current URI. I believe something like this.

```
$currentPath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($currentPath == $public) {
    // do logic
} else if ($currentPath == $admin) {
    // other logic
}
```